# Why is maven using the wrong repository when multiple dependencies in different repos?

Tags: maven

I have a settings.xml file that has the following...

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /jpmc-public -->
            <id>PRIVATE-SNAPSHOT</id>
            <mirrorOf>PRIVATE-SNAPSHOT</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://url1</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>PRVATE</id>
            <mirrorOf>PRIVATE</mirrorOf>
            <url>https://url2</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>public</id>
            <mirrorOf>*,!PRIVATE,!PRIVATE-SNAPSHOT</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://url3</url>
        </mirror> 
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>public</id>
                    <url>http://url</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>PRIVATE-SNAPSHOT</id>
                    <url>https://url1</url>
                    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>PRIVATE</id>
                    <url>https://url2</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>public</id>
                    <url>http://url3</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    ...
</settings>
```

Then I have something like this in my pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>public-lib</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>come.other.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>private-lib</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.test}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependency>
```

But when I run it tried to get the public lib from the private repo and fails. If I edit the settings to remove the repository tags then it gets the public stuff fine but fails trying to get the private stuff from the public repo. How am I supposed to say that a specific dependency comes from a specific repo?

Comment: Please throw away your first two mirror definitions and then try again.

Comment: Actually I think I might have been wrong I am testing that iteration now

Comment: Give me a bit to confirm but it looks like that may have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general situation is as follows:

1. You *cannot* define which repository a given dependency is drawn from.
2. You *need not* define which repository a given dependency is drawn from. Maven looks into *all* repositories and only fails if none of them contains it.

But:

- You can confuse Maven by wrong mirrors in the `settings.xml`.
- In rare cases, Maven resolution brakes if one of the repositories is broken.

In a company, it is usually the best idea to run a Nexus or Artifactory and add all the relevant local and remote repositories to it. Then you can point just to that Nexus/Artifactory as a mirror in your `setttings.xml`.